# Get the layout of other running apps in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, view

Is there a way I can get the hierchary view/layout of other running android apps? If that's not possible, could I possibly unpack the app's .apk file and get the information there? For example, there's a setting in developer options that allows you to get the bounds of every elememt on the screen [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZlXZ.jpg)

**EDIT**

I have come to realize that this is not allowed and goes completely against the Android SDK. I apologize for this error and will look more closely in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that Google blocks any of this because it would require me to inject my own code into other apps, which is not allowed due to malicious behavior in past apps.